# How can I give top blank when I add textview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am doing an app like whatsup. My question is about interface. I can get a message desc and parse it. After that I can add layout programmatically but it is writing same coordinate all the time. I tried `tv.layout(l, t, r, b)` and tv.setTop but doesn't work.

Where is my issue?

```
  bubbleLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutbubble);

  for(int i=0;i<msgid.length;i++){
      RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

      // Creating a new TextView
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText(msgdesc[i]);
      tv.setTop(20);        

      // Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

      // Setting the parameters on the TextView
      tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

      // Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
      bubbleLayout.addView(tv);
```

My XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1300dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:background="#084B8A" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messagetitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12pt" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutbubble"
        android:layout_width="1300dip"
        android:layout_height="500dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1300dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/replytext"
            android:layout_width="1000dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1050dp"
            android:background="#084B8A"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12pt" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen Shot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem.Changed my `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` in the xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutbubble"
        android:layout_width="1300dip"
        android:layout_height="500dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

And change my code as follows:

```
bubbleLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutbubble);
for(int i=0;i<msgid.length;i++){  
    // Creating a new TextView
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(msgdesc[i]);
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 0);         
    bubbleLayout.addView(tv);         
}
```

That is it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using RelativeLayout or a normal LinearLayout?

Try using a LinearLayout with `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: I update my question.It was android:orientation="vertical" stil

Comment: Yeah but you are adding them to a RelativeLayout, but the TextViews need to be directly in an vertical LinearLayout. But before you try to fix it, why don't you use a ListView like WhatsApp does? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Comment: Ahh Whatsup use listview?? I didnt understand what does it.Can you explain to me? I misunderstand actually how can i show left and right.I thought they just add layout programmatically.

Comment: See this Tutorial for ListAdapter you can basically make one row for every message.: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22973/discussion-between-duyguk-and-thommy)